# Error Comes when try to create AVD : “This AVD may not work unless you install…first”?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to create AVD for Android 5.0.1 with Google API. but it gives me warnings

This AVD may not work unless you install the Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a) system image for Android 5.0.1 (API 21) first.

i have installed that images but still that warning comes.

[image]

[image]

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change skin from `HVGA` to `No Skins`.

After then you may need to give it a couple of attempts, as emulator might experience a crash or two, given its beta release. If such an issue arises, just reboot your PC.

And follow the steps using this link

http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-install-android-5-0-lollipop-windows-pc-1479140